# What would be a neutral phrase to use to refer to someone who yearns for their life to have a coherent narrative?

Tags: phrase-requests

As stated in the title, is there a word or phrase that could concisely express this sentiment, or refer to the concept of this type of belief/hope. Romanticist almost fits in my mind, but this word also refers to the 18th-century movement which makes it ambiguous.  Thanks for any help in advance!

By *neutral* I mean a phrase that preferably has no excessive positive or negative connotation.

(*Coherent narrative* as in a narrative alike that in a scripted book or show; a narrative with a meaningful arc)

Comment: What do you mean by a _coherent narrative_?

Comment: Something like "*his poetic mood expressed romantic melancholy*" ?

Comment: “I feel I’m in season 5 of my life and the writers are just making ridiculous shit happen to keep it interesting.”

Comment: @KillingTime; coherent narrative as in a narrative alike that in a scripted book or show: a narrative with a meaningful arc.

Comment: **to yearn for a life with meaning**

Comment: Karl Popper wrote a lot about this, but he wasn't exactly neutral. You could also check out Lyotard.

Answer (score 1):

Meaningful Life

You could say, 'in order to have a meaningful life, you might benefit from finding an overall theme, to fit your various experiences to, that feels comfortable to you and makes your life feel cohesive and significant'.

https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/meaningful-life

Answer (score 0):

If you want a *derogatory* term for this sort of attitude, the slang term **main character syndrome** might fit. [Wiktionary defines it as:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/main_character_syndrome)

> The phenomenon of thinking of oneself as the protagonist in the movie of one's life (and, thus, usually as unrealistically important or distinguished).

Comment: Thank you for your answer; this is a great phrase for anyone who finds this looking for a derogatory phrase, but I am personally after a phrase that is not charged if such a one exists!